# jQuery used to change multiple values on html texts with dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html code :

```html
<div class="option">
  <h4 class="form-label">Quantité de data</h4>
  <select class="selectpicker" name="Quantité de data" id=datanb>
    <option value="10">10 gb</option>
    <option value="20" selected>20 gb</option>
    <option value="30">30 gb</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and these selects

```
<h4 class="form-label">Nombre de Semaine</h4>
<select class="selectpicker" name="Nombre de Semaine" id="weeknb">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>



<div class="option">
  <h4 class="form-label">Quantité de data</h4>
  <select class="selectpicker" name="Quantité de data" id=datanb>
    <option value="10">10 gb</option>
    <option value="20" selected>20 gb</option>
    <option value="30">30 gb</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

and I want to change the this code

```
<h2 class="price" id="lol"> 29€ - 1semaine - 20gb </h2>
```

the value 20 to be 10 or 30 depending the option value

I've tried this with jquery and is doesn't work.

```js
$('#datanb').change(function() {
  var nbweek = $('#weeknb');
  var price = temp + 9;
  $('#lol').text(price + '€ - ' + nbweek + 'semaine - ' +
    var temp = (this.value * nbweek) + 'GB');
});
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax: `$('#lol').text(price + '€ - ' + nbweek + 'semaine - ' +
    var temp = (this.value * nbweek) + 'GB');` - you need to remove the var temp = also this `var nbweek = $('#weeknb');` should be `var nbweek = $('#weeknb').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid syntax:

```
$('#lol').text(price + '€ - ' + nbweek + 'semaine - ' + 
  var temp = (this.value * nbweek) + 'GB');
```

you need to remove the var temp = also this: `var nbweek = $('#weeknb');` should be `var nbweek = $('#weeknb').val();`

Here is a fixed version

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datanb, #weeknb').on("change", function() {
    var nbweek = $('#weeknb').val(),
      gb = $('#datanb').val(),
      price = nbweek + 9;
    $('#lol').text(price + '€ - ' + nbweek + ' semaine' +
      (nbweek == "1" ? "" : "s") + ' - ' +
      (gb * nbweek) + 'GB');
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <h4 class="form-label">Quantité de data</h4>
  <select class="selectpicker" name="Quantité de data" id=datanb>
    <option value="10">10 gb</option>
    <option value="20" selected>20 gb</option>
    <option value="30">30 gb</option>
  </select>
</div>
<h4 class="form-label">Nombre de Semaine</h4>
<select class="selectpicker" name="Nombre de Semaine" id="weeknb">
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<h2 class="price" id="lol"></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#datanb').change(function() {
  var nbweek = $('#weeknb').val();
  var temp = this.value * nbweek;
  var price = temp + 9;
  $('#lol').text(price + '€ - ' + nbweek + ' semaines - ' + this.value + 'GB');
});


$('#weeknb').change(function() {
  var datanb = $('#datanb').val();
  var temp = this.value * datanb;
  var price = temp + 9;
  $('#lol').text(price + '€ - ' + this.value + ' semaines - ' + datanb + 'GB');
});
```

found by myself !

Best regard

Comment: Well done you! Finding it all by yourself ;) - However look up DRY :)